# expand alternative for Content, which exists for JS but not for XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I want to basically expand something in a list, and I am using XAML & C#.

How would I go about resizing an item in the list, and showing the items, and pushing the other items down?

An example of this exists [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br212658.aspx):

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that was a rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your example I think you're looking for what's called an [Accordion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.internal.pivot.controls.accordion%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control set on Single selection mode. Which should be available in whatever your developing with, at least that's what it looks like by your example exactly. Hope this helps :)